# Applying for a Thailand visa, but I don’t have a guarantor yet

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, thailand

I’m applying for a visa to Thailand. The visa requires:

- Purposed address in Thailand
- Name and Address of Local Guarantor
- Tel./Fax.
- Name and Address of Guarantor in Thailand

Do I 100% need a real contact in Thailand? Or can I put down a hotel name or some random organization? I'm traveling with a group and we haven't reserved a house or hotel just yet, but I'm the only one who needs a visa. Any chance my visa will get denied if they think I'm not being truthful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I applied for a Thai visa I left the Thailand address section empty and during the submission I was advised to fill in the details of hotel where I will be staying.

I don’t know if something has changed and it now possibly says Guaranter but if it’s just the Thai contact they are looking for it’s fine to put the hotel details.

Do not put any fake names there.

This is obviously anecdotal  so it may be different  for someone else.

Comment: Can i ask you how long it took for your Visa process? I’ve read about 5 business day.

Comment: I think it took 7 business days last time

Answer (score 2):

After reading this, back in 2018, I asked a [related / followup question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116502/guarantors-for-tourist-visa-for-thailand) to fully understand the *guarantor* thing.

[This webpage of the Thai Embassy in Italy](http://www.thaiembassy.it/index.php/en/consular-services/visa-application) still states, among the documents required for several types of touristic visa:

> 5. Hotel Reservation or invitation letter from the person who provides accommodation stating period of stay and full address of the accommodation. Signed copy of the accommodation provider’s identity card is also required.

I then wrote them an email and their explicit answer was:

> As regards point 5), it is sufficient to present a copy of the hotel reservation.

I finally booked online my first three nights in Bangkok and attached the full address of the hostel to my visa request. Then I was in Thailand for over one month, visiting a dozen different cities and islands counrtywide but I firmly believe that - reasonably - including the address of your first stop-over is enough.

Of course all considerations apply to non-covid times but this item in the list of requirements is not really pertinent with the pandemy: other conditions may get more restrictive but not this one in particular.