# Guarantor(s) for tourist visa for Thailand

Tags: visas, paperwork, tourist-visas, thailand, terminology

I am about to apply for the first time for a multiple-entry tourist visa for Thailand and I am a bit struggling to understand all the requirements and the fields to fill in.

Particularly, the last thing I miss and I want to get precisely is about the *guarantor* or guarantors; the [Application for Visa](http://www.thaiembassy.it/images/application_for_visa.pdf) mentions both:

> Local guarantor and address

and

> Guarantor and address in Thailand

I'd like make sure if this, or these, may be the hotel/hostel were I'm sleeping or **must** be somebody else.

Reading *[Applying for a Thailand visa, but I don’t have a guarantor yet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108070/applying-for-a-thailand-visa-but-i-don-t-have-a-guarantor-yet)* didn't make it much clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *local guarantor* is where you are currently applying for the visa.  You can just put the hotel where you are staying.  Often times if you use an "agent" you would just put their name there (or it would be pre-filled in).  In some cases, you can even leave it blank.

The *Guarantor in Thailand* is just someone that you know you will be visiting in Thailand.  It could also be the guesthouse or whatever of where you are staying.

I want to remind the readership that these 2 sections are the *least important* parts of the Thai Visa application and are nothing to lose any sleep over.